# DevExpress Spreadsheet in Razor Pages where the DxDocumentRequest() function is not being called, resulting in the failure to load spreadsheets

Tags: c#, devexpress, razor-pages, devextreme, devexpress-mvc

I am implementing a Spreadsheet module,
which includes displaying spreadsheet..

the chtml/view for razor page

```
   @(Html.DevExpress()
.Spreadsheet("spreadsheet")
.Height("600px")
.DocumentRequestHandlerUrl(Url.Page("Index", "DxDocumentRequest"))
.Open(Model.FilePath)
.Ribbon(x => x.Visible(false))
.ClientSideEvents(events => events
 .OnSelectionChanged("function(s, e) { handleSelectionChanged(e.selection.activeCellRowIndex, e.selection.activeCellColumnIndex, s.getActiveSheetName(), s.GetActiveCellValue()); }")))
```

and the cs file code

```
   public IActionResult OnPostDxDocumentRequest()
    {
        return SpreadsheetRequestProcessor.GetResponse(HttpContext);
    }
```

namespace :

```
 test.Web.Areas.Investor.Pages.SpreadsheetConfig;
```

tried making a controller , didnt work, used `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` same